# Nested Sass accessing

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm new to CSS and Sass. I'm not sure how to change the appearance of my page. I've been reading the Sass documentation and thought I'd play around with a little twitter bootstrap to try and practice.

Sample code:

```
<div class="user_nav">
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JobPost</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

If I were to change the CSS of say class navbar-header, would this be the Scss code?

```
.user_nav {
   .navbar-wrapper {
      .container {
         .navbar-header {
             change here
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try it and find out?  Is there an error?  What is the error?

Comment: Your above code generates: `.user_nav .navbar-wrapper .container .navbar-header { }`. Isn't this a little bit too specific? What is your actual question?

Comment: @cimmanon I'm not sure how to try this out. There is no error but I'm not sure show to access that particular portion of the HTML

Comment: @NicoO I am trying to change the CSS of that particular class but I'm not sure how to access this specific portion

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You don't know how to use the inspector in your browser to debug the CSS?  You don't know where to view errors that would be generated by Sass?  You don't know how to compile Sass?

Comment: You [should install sass first](http://sass-lang.com/install) and play arround with it. You may just write normal css, like you know it. You don't need to address every nested item. [This article could also help you](http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule)

Answer (score 3):

What you need to know about SASS is that for these kind of frameworks the best is to not override with new CSS but override the SASS parameters defining colors/typography etc. of the framework.

For example for bootstrap you can look into _variables.scss on what you can change. For your example you could lookup navbar and find:

```
$navbar-height: 50px !default;
```

Now if you want to override this, you can do that as long as you redefine the SASS parameter after you've imported the _variables.scss file. If you look at bootstrap.scss you'll find that as with most frameworks they attempt at splitting all of this up in components. Ie the following is the first lines from bootstrap.scss:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
...
```

Then further down you'll see the components listed, this is where you can leave out any components you don't use to avoid bloating your CSS files. So instead of using bootstrap.scss, you can create your own copy of that file, and remove the components you dont need - aswell as redefine parameters set in variables if needed. Ie: (mybootstrap.scss):

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

//override navbar height
$navbar-height: 150px; //you want to omit the !default as it only assigns the variable if it doesn't have a value already.

// Reset and dependencies
...
```

In some cases you can't get around without adding additional CSS to override the styles of your framework. Then what you want to do is lookup whatever you want to override in the sass files. So forexample if I look in bootstraps _navbar.scss component file ill find that:

```
.navbar-header {
  @include clearfix();

  @media (min-width: $grid-float-breakpoint) {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Meaning I could just add the following in my _customOverrides.scss file that i import at the end of mybootstrap.scss - in order to override for example the navbar-header breakpoint for the grid-float.

```
.navbar-header {
   @media (min-width: 500px) {
      float: left;
   }
}
```

Hope those tips will help - and I'm sure once you get used to the SASS workflow you'll never go back! :)

Comment: This does not answer the question, as it stands the question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: I disagree, he says that "I'm new to CSS and Sass. I'm not sure how to change the appearance of my page." and asks how to change the css of the navbar-header through SASS.

Comment: "I don't know how to Sass" is too broad (and we close questions that are too broad around here).  The OP failed to explain *why* their code doesn't work, you're just enabling them.

Comment: @cimmanon I understand that my question is quite broad but being new to the subject I find it difficult to ask a specific question as I do not know the terminology and key terms.